# Creating and mounting a new file system on CentOS

Tags: centos, filesystems

On my CentOS machine I have to create a new partition/file system, not sure which one I need to be honest I am a little bit confused about it all. If someone could explain it and walk me through it that would be great.

The current size of my Harddisk is 190GB, but I am only using 100GB of that.

When I do `df -H` I get the following output (these are file systems if my understanding is correct?):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        94G   65G   25G  73% /
tmpfs           938M  1.1M  937M   1% /tmp
tmpfs           1.0G   18M 1007M   2% /var/log/httpd
```

When I launch `parted` and use the `print` command, I see the following output (these are partitions if I understand this correctly?):

```
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: ATA QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 193GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      65.5kB  193GB  193GB  primary  ext3         boot
```

How can I create a new file system to fill up the remaining space in the partition? I would like to mount this file system on a directory "/home/admin/admin_backups/", so that I can store all my backups on this new file system.

Alternatively it would also be a solution to resize the current file system, what are the advantages/disadvantages of using one or the other approach?

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency between the output of `df`, which reports the partition as 94GB in size, and `parted`, which says it's 193GB. Did you take this output at the same point in time?

Comment: Yes, I fired both commands in the same minute.

Comment: I suggest running [`lsblk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html) to get a better glimpse of the disk usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your partition seems larger than your filesystem, try growing the filesystem:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Can I do this on a live server or should I reboot into rescue mode?

Comment: Linux has supported online resizing for ext3/4 for quite some time. I routinely grow filesystems without rebooting.

Comment: Thank you, are there any risks? If I understand this correctly this will just resize the filesystem to the maximum allowed size by the partition?

Comment: By default it maximizes the filesystem. The [man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) has more details.

Answer (score 1):

What you have:

- a single disk, 193GB in size, known to the system as `/dev/sda`
- inside there is one primary partition, taking up all the disk space, known as `/dev/sda1`
- this partition is formatted as ext3, and is mounted as the root of your filesystem: `/`

I suggest using `gparted` if you have a graphical environment on that host, it is much more intuitive to figure out what you have and what you can do with it than with the CLI version.

With it you can resize existing partitions and create new ones. I suppose you'll want a new primary partition at the end of the disk, which will end up as `/dev/sda2`, and can then be mounted to your desired location. Add a line to `/etc/fstab` to mount it automatically at boot time.

Comment: I do not have a graphical environment. What makes you think that the partition takes up all the space on the drive? When I look at the output of `df` the partition only uses 94GB

Comment: see the answer by @ptman above, it seems that the filesystem wasn't created with the full partition size. you can tell this from the `parted` output, which reports size of 193GB for the partition.

Comment: Thanks, it would be good to adjust your answer as right now the information is incorrect.